# How can I save the modification of open source library that my project dependens on?

Tags: git

I modified some open source library my project depends on. But the node_modules folder is ignored. In this case, every time I clone the project and execute `npm install`, I need to change the source code of the dependency again. What is the best practices in this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

You have two different choices:

1. Make a pull request if you change is "general purpose" one and wait for your modification to be merged in the library.
2. Create a fork of the library, modify the code based on your needs, and request the fork instead of the original library.

Please, pay attention: if you create a fork, you need to "re-align" future modification when needed in order to get the updates.

Comment: i forked and made my edits, and i uploaded the library to my fork, but when i try to install it  i get an error because of the registry... do i ned to register in npm or something?